# jquery.ui.touch.punch.js script is preventing input functionality on touch devices

Tags: jquery-ui, input, touch

It took me a little bit, but I figured out that I can't click on my inputs because of the touch.punch script I'm using to enable jquery UI drag functionality on touch devices. Anyone familiar with this script know why that might be? The form actually resides down the tree of the parent object. Does anyone know a way I can override or force through the selection? I'm going to try binding events that force focus to the input right now but maybe someone here has some insight?

Comment: Forcing it through worked. I'll leave this page on here answered though for anyone else who may encounter this issue!

Comment: Excellent question! +1. You should however accept @Danwilliger instead!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To anyone who might wind up here with a similar situation using the very handy touch.punch hack, simply forcing the focus through on a click event will work just fine!

```
$('.input').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: Not in my case unfortunetly

Answer (score 19):

JEditable + jQuery UI Sortable + jquery.ui.touch-punch

I have spent all day on this problem and I finally figured out the solution.  The solution is very similar to kidwon's answer.  However, I was using jeditable which dynamically creates input fields without class names.  So I used this conditional statement instead of checking the class name:

```
//Check if element is an input or a textarea
if ($(touch.target).is("input") || $(touch.target).is("textarea")) {
  event.stopPropagation();
} else {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

I think this is a better solution as it always uses the native functionality for any input or textarea fields.

Comment: You could likely simplify this even further by using `:input` instead of `input` and `textarea`:

//Check if element is an input or a textarea
    if ($(touch.target).is(":input")) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

Comment: This answer worked for me using Lisa's shortcut. I needed to consider selectboxs also, which it also covered.

Answer (score 14):

The other two answers here did NOT work for me, but Danwilliger's solution works; however, it's not clear from his answer how exactly to set it up in the Touch Punch JS file. Here's what to do. Again, this is Danwilliger's solution -- I'm just clarifying.

Change this section in jquery.ui.touch-punch.js (on approximately line 30):

```
function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {

// Ignore multi-touch events
if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
  return;
}

event.preventDefault();

var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
    simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
```

To this:

```
function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {

// Ignore multi-touch events
if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
  return;
}
var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
    simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    
//Check if element is an input or a textarea
if ($(touch.target).is("input") || $(touch.target).is("textarea")) {
    event.stopPropagation();
} else {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OK here's another solution if your `textfield` whatever HTML element is ain't focusing,scrolling, selecting words, moving text cursor around the text and whatever different scenarios might come then you may override the **jquery.ui.touch.punch.js** script.
I assume that your element isn't the draggable one but probably a child of it as my case was.

Put a class on your html element, for example `class="useDefault"`.
Then go to the script file and find that part:

```
...
function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {

    // Ignore multi-touch events
    if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
      return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();

    var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
        simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
....
```

As you can probably see `event.preventDefault();` assures that **jquery.ui.touch.punch.js**
overrides the default behaviors of the browser. To prevent that for our particular class node, make the following modifications:

```
if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
  return;
}
var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
  simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
//As you can see here is your class element check
if (touch.target.className === "useDefault") {
  event.stopPropagation();
} else {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

This solution is tested with **webkit** browsers only and **jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.2** release.

Hope that quick solution helps, BR

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Danwilliger and @jeremytripp for the solution. Being that this issue has been known for years and yet has still not been worked into touch-punch author's Git repo, I forked it with the solution added here:

https://github.com/copernicus365/jquery-ui-touch-punch/blob/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js

I would be quite happy for the author to incorporate those few lines of a change into the original library and make this one unneeded then, but if that never happens, it's nice to have a single source file to reference.

Answer (score 2):

Jacob's answer worked with a slight modification—I found that using the `click` event resulted in inconsistent behavior on iPad, ios9 Safari. Sometimes I'd press once on a field and it would focus, other times I had to press three times. Changing `click` to `touchstart` solved the problem for me (I also used event delegation since my form was added dynamically):

```
$('form').on('touchstart', 'input,textarea',function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a handle. 
Add an icon inside  and use this to drag. Then the inputs work fine.

```
<li><span class="move">Move</span><input...../></li>

    $("#sortableList").sortable({

    handle: ".move"

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried adding the lines which Danwilliger mentioned, it did not do the trick for me.

What worked for me was

```
//Check if element is an input or a textarea
if ($(touch.target).is("input") || $(touch.target).is("textarea")) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(touch.target).focus();
} else {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

I am not really sure why the other answers posted did not work, but for anyone else out there if they have the same issue try my solution out :).

Answer (score 0):

Throttlehead's solution worked for me.  Simpler perhaps to just use the JQuery selectors to cover all inputs and textareas:

```
    $('input,textarea').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
```