# jquery.ui.ipad preventing focus on input fields on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I've got a site that uses jquery.ui.ipad.js for flipping through pages.  It's lovely, but loading this file is also preventing the ability to touch on an input field and input text.  Everything else works fine except touching (focusing) on an input field.

I can comment out jquery.ui.ipad.js and the input works fine.  In reading and researching, it looks like it is related to the prevenetDefault behavior, which I see plenty of in the jquery.ui.ipad.js file, but I'm not sure how to enable touching to focus on an input field.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

[here is a version of the jquery.ui.ipad file](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/source/browse/trunk/jquery.ui.ipad.js?r=2)

Comment: saw this very similar question as well, but didn't seem to do the trick:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539072/jquery-ui-touch-punch-js-script-is-preventing-input-functionality-on-touch-devic